# Flask-SocketIO batching up messages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I've installed Flask-SocketIO async test from

https://github.com/shanealynn/async_flask

I had to make some minor edits to get it working (didn't have brackets in print statement etc).   It works *except* that the numbers are not shown on the screen as they are received - but only displayed after 10-20 are received, when all the missing ones are displayed.  Putting in alerts() shows that the messages are received immediately - they are *not* being batched up at the server.

If I reply to the messages and then reply to these replies it does force the Javascript to output the numbers - but this is not sustainable and fails after a few minutes.

Problem is on MacOS with safari or with Opera - the example doesn't work at all for me yet with Chrome or Firefox.

I can use example chat apps with socket.io etc with no problem - the issue is just with streaming numbers to the browser.

I think the example uses gevent as the transport (that is in requirements.txt) - though I am a little hazy about how that all fits together.

Comment: So, I am not so sure any more that the problem is in the Javascript - the tests I did before using alert()s I did again and they did _not_ indicate the data had been received.....so could be in the transport.  I am looking at how I change the Middleware...

Comment: So - I fixed it, I needed to apply the gevent "monkey-patch" gevent.monkey.patch_all()